# как в селениуме указать видимую область?

Tags: selenium

Получаю  информацию Селениумом с сайта,но заметил что если не помещается в окно информация то драйвер ее не видит,если она за пределами окна.Есть какое то решение?Может окно как то на максимум взять или область указать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Видимо вы пытаетесь спарсить сайт с динамически подгружаемым контентом. Думаю, что вам нужна скорее прокрутка страницы до определенного момента или до конца страницы.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы изменить размер окна в selenium нужно использовать аргумент `window-size=`.
Вот пример использования на `python`:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()

options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")

DRIVER = 'chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(DRIVER, options=options)

driver.get('https://myresolutionis.ru/')

print(driver.find_element(value='idone').text)

driver.quit()
```